# kubuntu suddenly does not recognize external monitor

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, multiple-monitors, kde

How do I restore my KDE (plasma, whatever it's called these days) screen settings to its defaults?

Setting:

- Dell XPS 15 laptop with USB-C-attached dock
- Dell 34'' monitor connected to dock with miniDP (no difference with HDMI)
- Kubuntu 16.04.1 fully patched
- the `nouveau` nvidia driver is being loaded.

Until earlier today, the whole setup was working fine; the laptop screen is the "primary screen". Following an accidental removal of the USB-C cable, not only is the big monitor no longer lighting up, the laptop screen also turns black.

If I restart the machine without the monitor plugged in (but with the USB-C dock still connected), the laptop screen comes back. If I now plug in the big monitor again, everything goes black. The external monitor is telling me it's getting no video signal.

I can break out to a VTY with <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, and I see that everything is still running, and the (text-only) contents of the laptop screen are naturally mirrored to the external monitor.

I looked in `.xsession-errors`, but there is way too much noise in there to figure out what's different between starting with and starting without the external monitor.

I tried removing `~/.local/share/kscreen/*` and restarting, but the behavior did not change. I do not see any changes in `/etc/X11`. Not sure where else to look.

If I create a new user (with `adduser`) and I log on as *that* user from the login screen, everything works fine, so it must be something in some `~/.??*` directory.

I'm not sure what other details I should provide that will aid debugging, and this message is already long enough.